# Como mostrar un CardView dependiendo de otro en un RecyclerView desde un adaptador

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, cardview

Buen día, espero se comprenda la pregunta necesito mostrar un **CardView** luego de ejecutar una acción en otro **CardView**, por ejemplo: la funcionalidad que necesito es que cuando de clic al botón de mostrar situado en el **CardView** 1 (posición 0) me muestre el C**ardView** 2 (posición 1) de que manera podría hacer algo así? estuve tratando de validar por posición, también utilizando **for** o **while** pero no obtengo resultado, sin mas mostrare lo que tengo por el momento.

De entrada valido que solo muestre el **CardView** que esta en la posición 0, debido a que utilizo base de datos en realidad lo valido por el id pero tomémoslo como si fuera la posición 0 del **RecyclerView** para no darle muchas vueltas:

```
if (CierreCaja.lIdTipoPago != 1){
        cierreCajaViewHolder.cvCierre.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Cuando de clic al botón mostrar debería mostrar el siguiente **CardView** pero no se como validar para acceder a esa posición dinámicamente

```
cierreCajaViewHolder.aceptar.setOnClickListener(view -> {
cierreCajaViewHolder.cvCierre.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

cvCierre es la **CardView** y a simple vista esto no me funciona ya que aunque estoy asiganando que se muestre la **CardView** en ningún momento estoy diciendo que cual **CardView** se muestre

También trate de mostrar el **CardView** por posición asignado que muestre la posición actual + 1 pero tampoco funciona lo cual es lógico porque a `setVisibility` no se le puede pasar como parámetro una posición sin embargo eso es lo que busco que me muestre el siguiente **CardView**:

```
cierreCajaViewHolder.cvCierre.setVisibility(position+1);
```

Y eso seria todo espero se haya comprendido mi pregunta y espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar lo que deseas puede ser muy sencillo y la mejor opción es crear un adapter en donde puedas agregar nuevos `CardView`, debes detectar la posición del elemento al cual le das clic mediante:

```
  int selectedItemPosition = recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
```

al obtener la posición puedes indicarle a el Adapter que agregue el siguiente elemento, sumando 1 para obtener el siguiente indice y notificar al Adapter que elemento debe agregar usando [**notifyItemInserted()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)) :

```
        int addItemAtListPosition = selectedItemPosition + 1;
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(addItemAtListPosition);
```

> [**notifyItemInserted()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)) Notifica a los observadores
> registrados que el elemento reflejado en la posición se ha insertado
> recientemente.

De esta forma al dar clic a un elemento puedes lograr que se inserte el siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Revisa el ejemplo completo:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Adapter-Add-Remove-Elements

Comment: Hola Jorge gracias por tu respuesta, pero tengo un problema veo que el codigo lo pones a nivel de actividad no a nivel de adaptador y pues el boton aceptar del cardview esta en el adaptador no en la actividad entonces como podria adaptar el codigo para que se ejecute cuando de en el boton aceptar que esta dentro de la carta que se dibuja en el adapter.class

Comment: En el Adapter configuras el clicklistener y haces referencia a el clicklistener de la Actvity por ejemplo: view.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.myOnClickListener); , agregué el ejemplo para que veas como esta construido.

Comment: En el Adapter configuras el clicklistener y haces referencia a el clicklistener de la Actvity por ejemplo: view.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.myOnClickListener); , @AdielMoran agregué el ejemplo para que veas como esta construido. https://github.com/Jorgesys/Adapter-Add-Remove-Elements

Comment: Creas una interfaz que la implementara tu Activity y tu adapter la recibe, simplemente en tu adapter as Interfaz.Metodo() y eso hara que en tu activity se ejecute el metodo Metodo()

Comment: Lo que comenta Bruno es también una buena opción en lugar de llamar MainActivity.myOnClickListener.